# How to set the outline width in an input box using tailwind css?

Tags: html, css, tailwind-css

According to tailwind css official documentation, I can use outline-4 class to set outline width as 4px but when I am trying to write this on my HTML code, no changes in width of the outline is seen. Here is the code:

```
<input class="border-2 border-rose-600 block rounded-lg  outline-rose-600 outline-4">
```

This code only changes the color of the outline but no change in the width of the outline. Pls, help to fix this issue.

Comment: Add `outline` class also

Comment: you need to add ``outline`` class first

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One of thing is that you can use `border-4` only to thicken the border instead of `outline`. Another thing is that you can use `ring` class also.

```html
<script src="https://cdn.tailwindcss.com"></script>
<div class="flex flex-col space-y-8 p-10">
  <input class="block rounded-lg border-4 border-rose-600" />

  <input class="block rounded-lg ring-4 ring-green-600" />
</div>
```